# How does MAC spoofing happen?

Tags: mac-address

I know how to change my MAC address, but I want to know how does this happen, or how the programs that do so work.

Answer (score 3):

A better question is really: how does an ethernet interface get its factory MAC address?

In typical ethernet circuitry, the MAC address is actually always software, and additionally there is some variety of read-only memory which holds the factory address.  When the hardware is reset, the software address is set to the value of the factory address.  Depending on the hardware, it might need the OS to do this.

When you change the MAC address, all that happens is the driver tells the hardware "here's your new MAC address", normally by writing some control registers.

How does the driver talk to the hardware?  That's a topic for another forum.